How do I get the macOS app-specific Help menu search bar to appear?
I have a macOS app written in objective-c. Initially, I didn't want to provide a Help menu, so I removed the 'Help' top-level menu item from the storyboard.
Now I want to add a help facility, and still retain the system-provided menu search bar. I have added the Help menu and the submenu items needed for my app. But the search bar does not appear.
This is the menu search behavior that I am looking for:

When I add the Help menu item and submenu items back into my app via the storyboard, the search bar does not appear when I run the app. Is there some magic necessary to enable this behavior?

The first item in your Help menu should be an item that connects to the first responder showHelp method. Is it?

yes. I think I may have found the solution; I'll post an answer shortly.

This seems to resolve the issue. First, I assigned a value to the tag in the NSMenuItem titled 'Help', defining its value as TAG_HELP_MENU. Then, I added this code to the AppDelegate.h file, within the method applicationDidFinishLaunching:
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSMenu *menu = NSApplication.sharedApplication.mainMenu;
    for (NSMenuItem *item in menu.itemArray)
    {
        if (item.tag == TAG_HELP_MENU)
        {
            NSApplication.sharedApplication.helpMenu = item.submenu;
        }
    }
    return;
}

Now, I get the behavior I was looking for.

Here's the same answer, except backwards! This is someone who wants to remove the search bar!! Hahahaha. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075413/remove-or-customize-search-from-help-menu/41611855#41611855

And let's link to this too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964099/341994 I don't think it's sufficiently similar to make this one a duplicate but it's nice to have the link. — Don't forget to accept your own answer when the site lets you do so!

Thanks for your helpful comments. These are relevant links.
